# How to configure logging for SQL for EFCore 2 in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I know this sounds like an insanely stupid question, but I'm stuck.

In the [`Entity Framework > Entity Framework Core > Misc > Logging`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging) page (which incidentally hasn't been updated since Nov. 2016) it tells you to do the following:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder
        .UseLoggerFactory(MyLoggerFactory) // Warning: Do not create a new ILoggerFactory instance each time
        .UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFLogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
```

Sure enough if I do the following (adapting the above to the `ConfigureServices` method) I do get SQL output to the console / debug console when each command runs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyStoreContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connection);
    options.UseLoggerFactory(new LoggerFactory().AddConsole().AddDebug());
});
```

However the documentation for [`UseLoggerFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/53c365a3f7c6ade7e4701b32b0f3943ea24a5b27/src/EFCore/DbContextOptionsBuilder.cs) extension method clearly says:

> Sets the ILoggerFactory that will be used to create ILoggerFactory instances
>   for logging done by this context. It is never necessary to call this method 
>   since EF can obtain or create a logger factory automatically.
>
> There is no need to call this method when using one of the
>   'AddDbContext' methods.'AddDbContext' will ensure that the
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory used by EF is obtained
>   from the application service provider.

So it seems I'm not supposed to use it, and therefore I would assume it would just automatically use whatever I configure here:

```
services.AddLogging(options =>
{
    options.AddDebug();
    options.AddConsole();
}
```

However it doesn't. This outputs nothing to the console if I only configure logging 'globally' here.

What is the correct way to do logging in EFCore 2 under ASP.NET Core 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using .net core 2.1 with sdk 2.1.1 and I have it working this way with 2 different database providers (mysql and oracle).

I have file `appsettings.json` with the following configuration:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the Program.cs I import this

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

and pass it when building the webhost

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
       .UseConfiguration(config)
       .Build();
```

**Note:**

I add the db context to the DI just like you do but I didn't need to have this code :

```
services.AddLogging(options =>
 {
    options.AddDebug();
    options.AddConsole();
 }
```